# Want to make a for loop for the same data set for different restrictions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set where I am restricting what rows the data set reads:

```
# Use pandas to read in csv file
data_df_0 = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv')
#create data subsets based on specific buoy coordinates
data_df_1 = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv', skiprows=range(9,114))
data_df_2 = pd.read_csv('data_set.csv', skiprows=([i for i in range(1, 8)] + [j for j in range(21, 114)]))
```

I now what to write a for loop to assign different values based on the different dataset, my current attempt at the code is

```
# Assign variables according to header line (i.e., first row)
for x in range (0,2):
    lon_x = data_df_x['longitude']
    lat_x = data_df_x['latitude']
```

which gave me the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-3f7a5140aca4> in <module>
     18 # Assign variables according to header line (i.e., first row)
     19 for x in range (0,2):
---> 20     lon_x = data_df_x['longitude']
     21     lat_x = data_df_x['latitude']
     22 #     w_temp_x = data_df_x['temp (c)']

NameError: name 'data_df_x' is not defined
```

Where did I go wrong and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: kindly share a sample of ur dataset, with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that Python interprets "data_df_x" as a separate variable--not as "data_df_0" and "data_df_1" like you're wanting it to.

Instead, you can iterate through the dataframes, themselves:

```
longitudes = []
latitudes = []

for df in [data_df_0, data_df_1]:
      lon_x = df['longitude']
      lat_x = df['latitude']

      longitudes.append(lon_x)
      latitudes.append(lat_x)
```

if you need to keep track of the dataframe "number" you could instead do the following:

```
longitudes = {}
latitudes = {}

for i, df in enumerate([data_df_0, data_df_1]):
    lon_x = df['longitude']
    lat_x = df['latitude']

    longitudes[i] = lon_x
    latitudes[i] = lat_x
```

Comment: Will that also create lon_0, lon_1, etc? Or will I need to make a different for loop for that too?

Comment: It would not. However, I have edited my original answer to show how you might approach "saving" this information for access later